# Error install pecl/raphf and propro

Tags: php, pear, updating, php-5.5, php-7

I have updated php5.5 to php7.0.

I try to run this commande :

```
pecl install pecl/raphf
```

But I obtain this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /usr/share/php/PEAR/Frontend.php on line 91

How I can install  :

```
pecl install pecl/raphf
pecl install pecl/propro
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solving my problem :

I have unistalled php 7.0.5, and installed php 5 for get old pear version.

```
apt-get install php-pear

pear clear-cache

pear upgrade pear-1.10.0
```

Then, I am re-installed php7.0.5

It work !

Answer (score 5):

Try update PEAR:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

[Original Answer in GitHub Issue](https://github.com/gplessis/dotdeb-php/issues/123)

Answer (score 1):

Pear 1.10.0 supports php7.  Upgrade your pear.

http://pear.php.net/package/PEAR/download/1.10.0

Answer (score 1):

I solved my similar problem on Centos7.x for root user:

1. I'm remove default package:

   yum remove php-pear
2. Next i'm install package for php7.x (for example php7.1) and default package:

   yum -y install php71-php-pear && yum -y install php-pear
3. After install i'm find my php71-pear directory and create symlink instead of default php-pear:

   find / -type d -name 'pear'

> ...
>
> /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/share/doc/pear
>
> /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/share/pear
>
> /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/share/tests/pear
>
> ...

```
mv /usr/share/pear /usr/share/pear_5
ln -s /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/share/pear /usr/share/pear
```

4. Profit...

   pecl -V

> PEAR Version: 1.10.7
>
> PHP Version: 7.1.5
>
> Zend Engine Version: 3.1.0

Comment: Using my repository, you don't have to run all this stuff. Follow the wizard instructions https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/ with "single" version. More, all the extensions (propro, raphf, http, pq...) are there. No need to use the pecl command.

Answer (score 1):

Try update PEAR:

```
$ wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
$ php go-pear.phar
```

Comment: Whatch for: ** The 'pear' command is not currently in your PATH, so you need to
** use '/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/pear' until you have added
** '/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin' to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need uninstall PHP 7. You can edit /usr/bin/pear and set php=/usr/bin/php5. Then update PEAR.

I have install both php env like php5.6 and php7.1